# Unable to Create Table

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am not able to create a table. I am using Cassandra 3.10. When I create the  I get the following error. `Bad Request: Only clustering key columns can be defined in CLUSTERING ORDER directive`. My column is a primary key even still I am facing the problem.

My schema is

```
Table trends{
name text,
price int,
quantity int,
code text,
uitime timeuuid,
primary key((name,code),uitime))
with clustering order by (code DESC, uitime DESC)
```

Comment: code is part of the primary key, therefore it cannot be a clustering column. this article is interesting,especially the pictures since it shows how data is organized in cassandra when using clustering columns https://blog.ippon.tech/modeling-data-with-cassandra-what-cql-hides-away-from-you/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your composite primary key is *(name, code)* and your clustering key is *uitime*. So with the given schema you can only do:

**with clustering order by (uitime DESC)**

See:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCompositePartitionKeyConcept.html